# [mybatis]+ null check using StringTypeHandler not woking

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to perform a null check for the lastName column in my user table using `StringTypeHandler` provided by MyBatis. 
But when I am passing a `null` value for lastName, no null check, for lastName is being done by `StringTypeHandler` before updating the table.

I want to know the purpose of `***TypeHandler` provided by MyBatis.

```
public String buildUserUpdateQuery(User user, Long userId) {
    return new SQL() {
      {
        UPDATE(UserTable.NAME);
        if (user.getFirstName() != null)
          SET(ProgramTable.Column.FIRST_NAME + " = #{program.departmentId,jdbcType=INTEGER,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler}");
        //if (program.getLastName() != null)
          SET(ProgramTable.Column.LAST_NAME + " = #{program.programName,jdbcType=VARCHAR,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler}");
        if (program.getMiddleName() != null)
          SET(ProgramTable.Column.MIDDLE_NAME + " = #{program.programStatus,jdbcType=VARCHAR,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler}");


        WHERE(ProgramTable.Column.USER_ID + " = #{userId}");
      }
    }.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the official documentation of [MyBatis typeHandlers](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers):

> Whenever MyBatis sets a parameter on a PreparedStatement or retrieves
>   a value from a ResultSet, a TypeHandler is used to retrieve the value
>   in a means appropriate to the Java type.

Therefore, `TypeHandler` are used to transform/map the data read from the database from a database type to its java corresponding type and vice-versa. The `TypeHandler` are not used to do any `null` checks.

Considering the example of the `StringTypeHandler`, it converts any data from a database column type `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` and converts it to `java.lang.String` and vice-versa.